# Without page refresh views exposed filters have to work (without AJAX)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views, media

I want to create the Gallery like [Example gallery link](http://refaktorthemes.com/oyster/portfolio-masonry). Taxonomy filed in views exposed filters. Anyone guide to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanted to check

1. [Masonry Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/masonry_views)

> This modules defines a masonry grid view style using Masonry API
>   module.

1. [Isotope.js](https://www.drupal.org/project/isotope)

> Isotope.js provides David DeSandro's Isotope jQuery plugin to Drupal
>   as a library. Isotope is a display plugin that comes with several
>   unique layout modes for content, including the ever-popular "masonry"
>   layout. In addition, the plugin also provides several methods for
>   responding to user events like window resizing and real-time
>   sorting/filtering.

Here is a good tutorial on [Building a Dynamic Image Display with Drupal & Isotope](http://acrl.ala.org/techconnect/?p=3739)